# Get value from object by interface property?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a custom class:

```
class CalendarThematicPlanModel extends FilterMethods<ICalendarThematicPlanShort> implements IModel<W> {
    public constructor(public model?: ICalendarThematicPlanShort) {
        super();
    }

    public validField<ICalendarThematicPlanShort, K extends keyof ICalendarThematicPlanShort>(key:K) { 
        this.model[key];
    }
}
```

I tied to be sure that passed key in method `validField(key)`is definitely exists in interface `ICalendarThematicPlanShort` and in `this.model`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you define a generic parameter with the same name as the interface. And thus, `K` is a key of that generic type parameter and not of your interface:

```
class CalendarThematicPlanModel extends FilterMethods<ICalendarThematicPlanShort> implements IModel<W> {
    public constructor(public model?: ICalendarThematicPlanShort) {
        super();
    }

    public validField<K extends keyof ICalendarThematicPlanShort>(key:K) { 
        this.model[key];
    }
}
```